# Dual Boot with Two Different HDDs?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, bios

have two HDDs, one with Windows 8 installed on it, and one with Ubuntu 12.10 installed on it.

Seeing as Ubuntu is not installed alongside Windows, I can only assume that Windows doesn't even see Ubuntu.

My problem is that, I want to be able to select a device to boot from a bios menu. I know that Windows Boot Manager will not work and my bios keeps giving me the only option of selecting a "Boot First Device", which sequentially changes the boot priority via the bios permanently unless I change it back.

Ultimately I want to be able to have a choice when I turn on my computer, but am not given that option. My motherboard specs are as follows:

> Motherboard: Gigabyte Z68XP-UD3 (Intel Socket 1155)
>
> Bios: Award Software International, Inc. (Version 8)

Any ideas? Without having to change wires every time I wanted to load a different operating system? Or how to have a selection every time my computer is turned on, without changing the boot sequence?

Thank you so much! Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation where I have Windows on my primary HDD and Ubuntu on the other (obtained by breaking the RAID). I can choose between Windows and Ubuntu by setting my boot priority on to the Ubuntu HDD. However, it sometimes automatically boots into Windows without giving me options to choose Windows or Ubuntu (which I believe is because of the automatic reset of boot priority).

Vinu